# How to use Sync.Cond in creating a concurrent buffer?

Tags: go, concurrency

If I understand it right, I should be using mutexs when I want to handle multiple goroutines accessing a shared resource. I'm trying to handle a case where I have a slice of set capacity where items are enqueued and dequeued. I have it set up where there's one goroutine handling inserting n*n items and there's n threads removing items from the queue. Then I have 2 sync conditions to handle the case where the main thread tries to insert an item when the buffer is full and when the worker threads try to remove an item when the buffer is empty.

The problem is the code results in a deadlock and I'm not sure how to fix it. I think the deadlock occurs because the removal goroutines are stuck waiting at notEmpty.Wait() after the insert goroutine has finished inserting all items.

I tried to add a channel to signal when the insert goroutine is finished and all remove go routines stuck waiting should exit but the code still results in a deadlock.

go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ge6BlptQEwy

I'm not quite sure how to fix this or if I should not be using mutex for this case and instead be using a channel or something.

Apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm still very much a beginner at go.

Comment: share the code you tried

Comment: The code is in the go playground

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about why you're getting the deadlock. Adding the channel didn't help because once a remove goroutine is stuck waiting in the `Remove()` method, it's too late for it to notice that the channel was closed.

You can use a buffered channel instead of a slice, mutex, and condition variables. You can provide a `Close()` method for your buffer type which closes the channel. The `Remove()` method would then return a `bool` in addition to the data which would indicate whether data was actually received.

Here's a version of your code that uses that method:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type ConcurrentBuffer struct {
    dataChan chan interface{}
}

func NewConcurrentBuffer(maxSize int) *ConcurrentBuffer {
    buffer := &ConcurrentBuffer{
        dataChan: make(chan interface{}, maxSize),
    }
    return buffer
}

func (b *ConcurrentBuffer) Insert(data interface{}) {
    b.dataChan <- data
}

func (b *ConcurrentBuffer) Remove() (interface{}, bool) {
    data, ok := <-b.dataChan
    return data, ok
}

func (b *ConcurrentBuffer) Close() {
    close(b.dataChan)
}

func main() {
    buffer := NewConcurrentBuffer(8)

    // Number of threads
    n := 8

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Create n remove goroutines
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                data, ok := buffer.Remove()
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                fmt.Printf("Removed by goroutine %d: %d\n", id, data)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
                data := i * j
                buffer.Insert(data)
                fmt.Printf("Inserted %d\n", data)
            }
        }
        buffer.Close()
    }()

    wg.Wait()
}
```